# Is it possible to pass filename as argument for npm jade output?

Tags: node.js, npm, arguments, pug, command-line-interface

I have such a command in my package.json:

```
"jade-all": "jade scripts/jade/sources/ -o scripts/jade/html/"
```

It works perfectly, but can I pass the certain file name in order to compile not all of source but the single file, say **index.html**? How should that command be written in this case?
PS. I'm on Windows.